# TabPanel within TabPanel styling

Tags: css, gwt

My app's layout consists of a TapPanel, which holds another TabPanel. I'd like to have the two TabPanels look differently. Following the GWT tutorial on applying styles I did the following:

```
TabPanel innerTabPanel= new TabPanel();
//carriersTabPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
innerTabPanel.addStyleName("inner-tabPanel");


.gwt-TabPanel .inner-tabPanel{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This, however, did not have any effect whatsoever. Then I tried the following, but that didn't work either:

```
.inner-tabPanel{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So how I can style the two panels separately?

Comment: What kind of effect were you expecting? If all you're doing is changing the size from 100%x100% to 100%x100%, there won't be much to see. Or are you not showing us some code?

Comment: I expected to change to the width of the inner TabPanel to 100%, i.e. the width of the browser. The same result as the commented out statement //carriersTabPanel.setSize("100%", "100%"), which works ok.

Answer (score 0):

`addStyleName` will just cascade the new CSS Style Class on the element. Depending on how you have defined the CSS class, the new class may or maynot fully replace the original style.

If you intend to completely replace the default GWT styling for a widget instance with your style class, use `setStyleName`. This will replace all the current styles on the element with your new class.

If you need an in-between solution, use the setters from GWT `Style` wrapper, by invoking `getElement().getStyle()` on the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage values for width and height are relative to the parent, not the window. [As w3schools notes](http://w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_width.asp), % "Defines the width in percent of the containing block".

If you want to see the effect of your rules, try setting the `background-color` or `color` CSS property instead. For instance, `.inner-tabPanel { color: red}` will set the color of the text in the inner tab panel to red, assuming there aren't any other conflicting rules. In this and all other CSS debugging situations, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is the tool of first choice.

Comment: The containing block has the width of the window as carriersTabPanel.setSize("100%", "100%") in Java makes the TabPanel as wide as the window itself. I thought the problem was to do with the references of the div class elements. I will check your suggestion tonight.